# How to restore a database using mdf and ldf files in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Asking for expert opinion. A very unfortunate event happened. One of our PCs crashed few days ago. That PC had SQL Server 2008 installed. Unfortunately no backup was running on that server. We sent the disk to a data recovery place and looks like they can recover some of the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files.

We are particularly interested in 1 particular database.

My questions are:

1. Is this possible to restore a particular  database using corresponding mdf and ldf files?
2. Do we need to have any mdfs from the  system databases? Any other files we need to ask data recovery company to look for?
3. Steps and/or or best practices to restore that database into a new machine.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `Unfortunately no backup was running on that server.` Regardless of what happens here, I hope you have learned a valuable lesson.

Comment: Thank you guys for your feedback and help. Sorry, that long time did not respond. This is because the issue was solved and I forgot to tell.) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)
You can attach the database files to another instance if you have the mdf' and ldfs ( even with mdf you will be able to attach )

System database master contains the  user info, and msdb contains the jobs and other info;  if you couldn't recover these files, you need to add them manually

ssms -> rightclick database -> attach  ; choose the files and attach

OR

You may have to run a  'DBCC CHECKDB()' statement against the newly attached database

2)
You can copy the .mdf and .ldf files to a different server and just Attach them.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx

You will lose any server-wide logins created at the instance level but you will retain your database users.

Comment: 3)
If the database is not open, then I think the files could be damaged. see this support article from microsoft. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288809 


So I told you all the possible ways.)

Look at this resource, you might find more useful information.
https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/172/t/266070

Answer (score 6):

> 1. Is this possible to restore a particular database using corresponding mdf and ldf files?

Yes, you can try to attach them, probably just try to attach using:

```
CREATE DATABASE restored_copy_of_db_name
ON (filename = 'c:\temp\backup_of_mdf.mdf'),
   (filename = 'c:\temp\backup_of_ldf.ldf')
FOR_ATTACH;
```

It is very common for this to fail, because the log file gets damaged from this type of event (see [this post](https://sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-file-backups/) for reasons we don't rely on mdf/ldf files as backups), so then you can try:

```
CREATE DATABASE restored_copy_of_db_name
ON (filename = 'c:\temp\backup_of_mdf.mdf')
FOR_ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG;
```

> 2. Do we need to have any mdfs from the system databases?

If you're trying to restore full functionality out of the gate, then your attached database above will not include server-level logins, jobs, etc. So you *may* need `master` and `msdb` in order to recover some of that information (but I would attach it as a user database (`msdb_copy`), rather than replacing `msdb`, and try to restore `master` on a throwaway instance - see [this thread](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1090334-1550-1.aspx) for possible ideas here, but I would not be confident you'll get that info back).

> 3. Steps and/or or best practices to restore that database into a new machine.

Nothing really in addition to the above, except, once you have these databases back, **please** set up a proper backup and recovery plan, which should include periodically testing that you can *restore* your databases - the fact that a backup was successful is not enough to ensure you won't be doing this again.

Comment: Could you also mention in the answer how you'd verify that the attached MDF is valid. In this scenario it is highly likely that some portions of the MDF file would have garbage. Is it possible that `CREATE DATABASE FOR_ATTACH` completes successfully, even if some parts of the MDF file are overwritten by zeros or some garbage?

Comment: @Vladimir I doubt it, if the MDF file has been damaged or overwritten with garbage, that should be detected during the attempt to attach.